# Pyspark, not recognizing python package path. No such file or directory error

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, conda, pyenv

Following this document: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/python_packaging.html

I packaged the environment and kept in local and mentioned it in --archives as well as placed the environment in HDFS and mentioned it in --archives. No luck. Can someone please help me to fix this.

job.sh calls run_job.sh which then triggers the job.

job.sh

```
BASE_OUTPUT_PATH='/user/svc-edl_ei_dld/dummy/'
DEFAULT_RUN_DATE=`date +"%Y%m%d"`
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/opt/miniconda3/envs/ei/bin/python3
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/opt/miniconda3/envs/ei/bin/python3
export RUN_DATE=$1
export LatLonOutput=$BASE_OUTPUT_PATH/stationDistanceOutput/date=$RUN_DATE
export billboards=$BASE_OUTPUT_PATH/allAssets/
export speedpath=$BASE_OUTPUT_PATH/speedFilter/
export selectPointsPath=$BASE_OUTPUT_PATH/selectPointsDF/date=$RUN_DATE
export partition=10

echo "Running for date $RUN_DATE"

sh scripts/run_selectPoints.sh $RUN_DATE $LatLonOutput $billboards $speedpath $selectPointsPath $partition >> /aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee/fff/ggg/hhh.log 2>&1
if [ $? -ne 0 ];then exit 1 ; fi
echo "Run completed for job for date $RUN_DATE"
```

run_job.sh

```
date=$1
inputpath=$2
assetParquetPath=$3
speedFilterpath=$4
outputpath=$5
partition=$6


spark3-submit -v \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode client \
--num-executors 10 \
--driver-memory 8g \
--executor-memory 8g \
--executor-cores 4 \
--conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=6000 \
--conf spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold=-1 \
--conf spark.pyspark.python=/opt/miniconda3/envs/ei/bin/python3 \
--conf spark.pyspark.driver.python=/opt/miniconda3/envs/ei/bin/python3 \
--archives hdfs:///user/svc-edl_ei_dld/outfront/pythonLibraries/ei.tar.gz#miniconda3 \
--py-files python/file.py python/main_file.py $inputpath $assetParquetPath $speedFilterpath $outputpath $partition
```

Error

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.

: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 5) (tbldjftv0072d-hdp.verizon.com executor 3): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/opt/miniconda3/envs/ei/bin/python3": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Environment details
[image]

Answer (score 0):

We don't need an HDFS location for conda. Simply we can use the --archives /local/path/conda/env. It is likely failing as in the driver you have not set the pyspark python path to point to conda env.

```
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=./miniconda3/bin/python3
or --conf spark.pyspark.python=./miniconda3/bin/python3
--archives ei.tar.gz#miniconda3
```

If you still want to use HDFS then you will need to add:

```
--conf spark.yarn.dist.archives=hdfs:///user/svc-edl_ei_dld/outfront/pythonLibraries/ei.tar.gz#miniconda3
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=./miniconda3/bin/python3
or --conf spark.pyspark.python=./miniconda3/bin/python3
```

Comment: Why are you using ./miniconda3/bin/python and not /opt/miniconda3/envs/ei/bin/python3 because the later one is the full correct path.
I tried placing it in HDFS as well as local, same issue.

Comment: I used this with the assumption that the conda environment path starts with the environment name (in your code it is ei.tar.gz#miniconda3). If the structure is different then you need to update the path accordingly.

Comment: In general it will start with env. Also I am using ./ (local) since yarn.dist will copy the archives to the working directory.

Comment: Here is the updated script


`
spark3-submit -v \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode client \
--num-executors 10 \
--driver-memory 8g \
--executor-memory 8g \
--executor-cores 4 \
--conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=6000 \
--conf spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold=-1 \
--conf spark.pyspark.python=/opt/miniconda3/envs/ei/bin/python3 \
--archives /home/sD_ei/ei.tar.gz \
--py-files python/selectPoints.py python/main_selectPoints.py $inputpath $assetParquetPath $speedFilterpath $outputpath $partition
`

I have updated the initial post with environment details

Comment: Even after updating script i am seeing same issue

Comment: How are you building the .gz file ?
generally it is done as : conda pack -f environ_name -o archive_file_name.gz
In this way conda zip does not include /opt/miniconda3. It starts with your env folder name. In this case it will be ./ei/bin/python3
Also your archive should be  /home/sD_ei/ei.tar.gz#ei